# How to access JSON Array with escape characters

Tags: java, json, string

With reference to the JSON file here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/14mTDpmR_Qu8UXz-bMxddEfL0AcB60T_S8N8MDTMYf5U/edit?usp=sharing

I'm trying to read the **Projects** array, but it returns length as 0.
But there are values in the array.

Following is my code:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(IOUtils.toString(new URL("JSONFile URL Here"), Charset.forName("ISO-8859-2")));
            JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("projects");
            System.out.println(jsonArray.length());
```

But when I post the JSON file on an online JSON reader and store and read from that, it can read. So I'm guessing I'm not escaping characters properly. Could someone please help me read this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was accessing the JIRA api, and since I haven't authenticated, I got an empty JSON string. This was nothing to do with escape characters.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with this ;

```
InputStream is = new URL("your url").openStream();
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(readJsonFile(bufferedReader));
JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("projects");
System.out.println(jsonArray.length());
```

And your readJsonFile  method should be like this;

```
private String readJsonFile(Reader reader) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = reader.read()) != -1) {
        sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

[fastjson](https://github.com/alibaba/fastjson) seems to do what you need:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = JSON.parseObject("you json string");
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("projects");
System.out.println(jsonArray.size());
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! First of all, this is an "English only" site - to ensure everybody can understand your answer, please use English. If you can not, maybe you can use automated translation. Furthermore, please give code not as an image: This hardly helps anybody. As per formatting, please use the preview button. I will correct your post, that may be of help for you.